# Cross-Compiling GCC for ARM Android. Build Fails At GMP

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I'm at the end of my rope on this one.

I'm new to Android development.  I've read the GCC install documentation and parts of Embedded Android.  I'm trying to cross-compile gcc 4.7 using an Android NDK toolchain built with the make-standalone-toolchain.sh script.  I'm using the gcc and binutils source files from the NDK toolchain sources.

I copied the gcc-4.7 and binutils-2.23 into a directory gcc-src and created a 'build' directory alongside both, as follows:

```
    gcc-src/gcc-4.7
    gcc-src/binutils-2.23
    gcc-src/build
```

I've symlinked the sources for 
**bfd, 
gas, 
gprof, 
ld, 
gprof
opcodes** 
from binutils to the gcc-4.7 source directory.  I also ran the script in contrib/ that downloads the relevant sources for 
**gmp, 
mpfr 
mpc** 
and creates the appropriate symlinks

I've run configure with the (latest) following options:

```
    sh ../gcc-4.7/configure --prefix=/usr/arm --disable-option-checking --host=arm-linux-eabi 
    --target=arm-linux-eabi --with-sysroot=/usr/sysroot --with-build-sysroot=/usr/sysroot --with-build-time-tools=/usr/bin --program-prefix=arm- 
    --disable-multilib --with-cpu=arm7 --enable-languages=c,c++,lto --disable-werror --disable-nls CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc GCC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc 
    CFLAGS='-Wall -g -mfloat-abi=softfp -mbionic -mandroid -Wl,-lsupc++ -Wl,-lgnustl_shared' 
    CPPFLAGS='-Wall -g -mbionic -mandroid' LDFLAGS='-Wl,-lsupc++ -Wl,-lgnustl_shared' CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++ 
    LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld STRIP=arm-linux-androideabi-strip OBJDUMP=arm-linux-androideabi-objdump READELF=arm-linux-androideabi-readelf  
    AS=arm-linux-androideabi-as NM=arm-linux-androideabi-nm 
    LIBS='-lc -ldl -lm' CC_FOR_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc CPP_FOR_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc CXX_FOR_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi-g++ 
    GCC_FOR_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-ranlib LD_FOR_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi-ld 
    AS_FOR_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi-as NM_FOR_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-nm AR_FOR_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-ar 
    READELF_FOR_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi-readelf 
    OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi-objdump STRIP_FOR_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi-strip 
    host_configargs=--with-headers=/usr/sysroot/usr/include target_configargs=/usr/sysroot/usr/include
```

When I run make -d...or make -d all-host...it constantly fails when it tries to compile gen-fac_ui.c because it can't find the includes stdio.h, stdint.h or string.h.

I'll add the exact error tomorrow after I re-set my build directory and start again, but I wanted to post the details and problem tonight before I pass out.

Any help...is greatly appreciated.  I'm at a loss on this one.

**QUICK NOTE:**  I noticed that the binutils src directory contains an include/ folder...I'll try symlinking that into the gcc src directory and running 'make distclean' then '../gcc-4.7/configure && make again.'

**UPDATE:** symlinking include/ did not fix the problem.  Here's the error I'm continuously getting

```
    make[2]: Entering directory `/project/android/tc-src/gcc/gcc-src/build/gmp'
    gcc `test -f 'gen-fac_ui.c' || echo '../../gcc-4.7/gmp/'`gen-fac_ui.c -o gen-fac_ui
    Putting child 0x007ddd30 (gen-fac_ui) PID 25531 on the chain.
    Live child 0x007ddd30 (gen-fac_ui) PID 25531 
    ../../gcc-4.7/gmp/gen-fac_ui.c:20:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
    ../../gcc-4.7/gmp/gen-fac_ui.c:21:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from ../../gcc-4.7/gmp/gen-fac_ui.c:23:
    ../../gcc-4.7/gmp/dumbmp.c:42:20: error: string.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from ../../gcc-4.7/gmp/gen-fac_ui.c:23:
```

Comment: are you cross-compiling gcc or cross-native gcc for arm?To cross-compile gcc you still 3 more dependencies i.e GMP MPFR and MPC

Comment: Not entirely sure what that means...I'm using --build=build --host=arm-linux-eabi and --target=arm-linuxeabi.  I have the sources for GMP MPFR and MPC downloaded into the gcc-4.7 source directory so that they will be compiled with the gcc build

Comment: `--host=arm-linux-eabi and --target=arm-linuxeabi ` This means you trying to cross-native which the resulting binary will be executed in arm board . Can u share your configuration  details?

Comment: Included them in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully compiled gen-fac_ui by doing the following:

1. Uninstalling the build gcc which is not (I think) needed as I'm using the cross-compiler toolchain generated by the make-standalone-toolchain.sh script from the Android NDK
2. Configuring the appropriate variables to set up the cross-compiler tools as the BUILD tools.

I have a different problem now, which I'll post in a different question.  Basically, while gen-fac_ui compiles, it (of course) won't run.